Do I need a fuse for each device connected to an AC-DC power supply?
I have 14 single board computers (SBCs) that each require 5 V, 5 A DC power. I have a 5 V, 60 A power supply that I want to use to power 12 SBCs. I also have a 12 V to 5 V 20 A DC-DC converter which I plan to use for the remaining two SBCs.
Do I need to put a fuse between each SBC and the power supply or DC-DC converter, or can I simply connect the SBCs? I have read somewhere that devices draw only the current they need, but I'd rather be safe than sorry.

Welcome! Legally? Electrically? Are you ok with a single failure bringing down all of them?

You are confusing why you need a fuse. The devices draw what they draw regardless of fuse or no fuse. the point is, if something goes wrong, what burns up in flames first - fuse, or lacking the fuse, the supply, the wires, or the SBC.

5V, 60A means insane wiring and will be hard to source in the first place. Are you sure you need exactly this PSU strategy?

Fuses protect wiring, not devices.1
If each SBC is wired separately to the 60 A PSU with wires that can only handle 5 A, then each one should have a 5 A fuse.
If all of the wiring can handle the full 60 A of the power supply, then strictly speaking you don't need a fuse, but you'll run the risk of some fairly spectacular failures.

1 It is well-understood that electronic devices fail in order to protect fuses!

"It is well-understood that electronic devices fail in order to protect fuses!" — to not confuse some people, it is an ironical statement, as one of Murphy's (or Stapp's) Laws: "A transistor protected by a fast-acting fuse will protect the fuse by blowing first." or "A $300 picture tube will protect a 10½ fuse by blowing first " (Source: A Mostly Complete List of Murphy's Laws)

Fuses protect wiring. Note that there is not just the wiring from the power supply to the device, but there is also wiring inside the device. I doubt the SBCs the OP is going to use have wiring and/or PCB traces that can handle 60A, so to prevent setting the PCBs on fire, a 5A fuse per SBC sounds like a good idea. I guess setting an SBC PCB on fire is one kind of what Dave Tweed alluded to by "some fairly spectacular failures".

@MichaelKarcher: Yes, exactly right.

Besides wiring, fuses also protect systems.  If a 5 A device fails and suddenly tries to draw 100 A, that will cause the 60 A supply to either shutdown due to built-in overcurrent monitoring, or fail.  Either way, the other 11 devices lose power without warning.  Fuse each load device independently.
Also, fuse the input of the DC/DC converter.  That one might have to be a slow-blo type, because DC/DC converters can draw a significant inrush current at startup that needs to be (briefly) ignored.
And - fuses do protect devices.  A fuse can be the difference between a repairable component failure and a board destroyed by fire, melted traces, etc.

"fuses do protect devices" - in practice, fuses often make little difference in subsequent repairs. For instance, I recently had a problem on my laptop with one of the USB ports, which was "repaired" by replacing the entire motherboard PCB (which means everything except battery, keyboard, SSD and screen). Nobody bothered to re-populate the USB hub IC which lost one port.

@DmitryGrigoryev It depends on motivation to find the core problem specifically (expensive on time, cheaper on material) or do it fast and foolproof (cheap on time, more expensive on material).

The thing to remember is that if a fuse blows, then the downstream device is already dead, and you are trying to prevent it from causing additional damage. @DaveTweed mentioned that you should size the fuse to protect the wiring connecting it to the supply, which is the primary consideration, but since you have several other loads connected to the same supply, the secondary protective function of the fuse is to remove the malfunctioning load from the power supply before the power supply's protective functions kick in and take down the entire system.
I recommend measuring the actual current draw of the SBCs while running. Not to resize the fuses, which should still be 5A (make sure your interconnecting wiring is capable of handling 5A), but to ensure you have sufficient headroom on your power supply. Most power supplies don't take well to extended operation at 100% output. 20% headroom is good, more is better. This also will help prevent a fault on one of the SBCs from causing the power supply to shut down/fold back on overcurrent.

Conventional fuses are usually too slow to prevent losing power in such failures. A fuse rated for 10 A will let 100 A through for 1-10ms, plenty of time to trigger an overcurrent protection on the PSU. You'd need to use power switch ICs to prevent total power loss.

In theory you don't need it (you're not required to comply to some standards) since it appears that you plan to use that circuit as a private user.
But it would be recommended for two reasons:

If one sbu fails but is not a complete hard short circuit, let's say it draws 10 A, and the other sbus are not at full load, the power supply will probably not see any over current, but the failed sbu will be in risk of overheating, so that might be a fire hazard.

In order to protect the power supply and the other sbus. In case the power supply detects the failure of an sbu as an abnormal condition then the power supply will work as a as a current limiter. What happens with the other sbus when the power supply deals with a short circuit depends on how well the power supply was designed to deal with output short circuits, maybe there will be a transient that could damage the other sbus.


By the way, a 60 A power supply to power 12x5 A loads seems too tight dimensioned, I would choose at least 65 A, better 75 A to have some safety margin
